# Not able to copy entire content from sql results in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a query which fetches a column from a table whose data type is VARCHAR(MAX).It returns only 1 row which is very long(actually its a XML file text).I need to copy that entire content from that column..I am not able to do that as it copies text to certain length.How do I get that entire content.Please help!!!!!

Comment: How long is the longest entry you need to copy?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One of

- Use grid mode (Ctrl+G) in SSMS and copy there (not text mode)
- If it's XML, then use `CAST (MyCol as XML)` and  it opens in a new query window on click

Answer (score 1):

This method works even when the content is extra long like image data:

1. Go to Edit 200 rows
2. Copy cell